# Bash scripting [keyboard input needed]

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I'm new in Linux and I'm trying to make my first bash script to improve  my work at college. Im working with a software called GROMACS and I'm trying to make a script to perfom a bunch of codes at the same time, but in one of the lines I need needs an input (number) from the keyboard. What can I do to make this script work?

Here are my lines:

```
!#/bin/bash
gmx pdb2gmx -f protein_name.pdb -o protein_name_processed.gro -water spce
```

And that last line needs the keyboard input (number 15)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unrelated to your question:  You will need to swap the `!` and `#` so your first line reads `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is some sort of a scientific software and it should be able to accep input from the pipe. You can try:

```
echo "My input string" | gmx pdb2gmx -f protein_name.pdb -o protein_name_processed.gro -water spce
```

if you have spaces in your string, the double quotes are not optional. If it is a single word input, you can skip them.

Comment: Thank you very much MelBurslan for your help. It works. I really appreciate it.

Comment: if this answer solved your problem, you should Accept it and mark the question as "answered" by clicking on the big tick to the left.